# How to create a function that reads in multiple files?

Tags: c++, function

Hi Im working on a application that I want to create a functions that reads in files 
ex.

```
readFiles()
{ 
   f1, f2=NULL, f3=NULL;
}
```

but I'm having a hard time getting multiple files to load. I would like to make a function that reads in the files and sets them to a specified variable for use in other functions within my program. Any help or ideas would be great. Thanks again! Ps. This is NOT a homework assignment.

Comment: Do you know how to read **one** file?

Comment: Yes i do know how to read in one file.

Comment: Then what's the problem reusing the code for reading several files? And what's the "hard time" you have reading multiple files? What have you tried?

Comment: I am able to open one file by user input of fileName and then opening and continuing with the rest of the program. But now I want to be able to ask the user to enter another file name to be opened and then continue with the rest of the program using data from the both files entered and opened.

Comment: I am using other functions to load the file and perform the other tasks for such file. I just dont understand how the file can be read with multiple variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would start by writing a function that can read ONE file. The call that function from another function that knows what files need to be read.

For example, assuming the files aren't enormouse (gigabytes large), you could do a function that reads a file into a single string:

```
 std::string readfile(std::string name)
 {
     ifstream f(name.c_str());
     std::stream tmp;
     std::stream res;
     while(getline(f, tmp)
     {
       res += tmp;
     }
     return res;
 }


 void somefunc()
 {
    std::string file1 = readfile("file1.txt");
    std::string file2 = readfile("file2.txt");
 }
```

Of course, if the file is a list of integers, you may want to read the data into a vector of integer instead. If the content is more complex, reading into a vector or struct or class would also work. But the basic principle applies [assuming the several files have the same general type of content at all, of course].

Comment: Thank you for your help this makes complete sense i will look into this way of reading in files. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at `ifstream`? Look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/

Are you passing in streams to the functions or the actual file names? You need to create multiple streams for multiple files, unless you want to work with one file at a time. You would have to do something like this:

```
ifstream nameOfStream ("Name of File");
```

to create the stream. You don't even need to do this in a function. If you have all the file names you could do this:

```
ifstream stream1(file1);
ifstream stream2(file2);
ifstream stream3(file3);
```

Edit: If you want to do it with one stream:

```
ifstream stream1(file1);
//Do something with stream
stream1.close();
stream1.open(file2);
```

Comment: how could i make is so the user is asked to input the file name and then call open to the next file?

Comment: Take a look at `cin`. You might also want to use this tututorial that talks about the basics of C++. http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/. They have a section on basic input and output.